# Matplotlib using Wedge() in polar plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

**TL/DR**: How to use `Wedge()` in polar coordinates?

I'm generating a 2D histogram plot in polar coordinates (r, theta). At various values of r there can be different numbers of theta values (to preserve equal area sized bins). To draw the color coded bins I'm currently using `pcolormesh()` calls for each radial ring. This works ok, but near the center of the plot where there may be only 3 bins (each 120 degrees "wide" in theta space), `pcolormesh()` draws triangles that don't "sweep" out full arc (just connecting the two outer arc points with a straight line).

I've found a workaround using `ax.bar()` call, one for each radial ring and passing in arrays of theta values (each bin rendering as an individual bar). But when doing 90 rings with 3 to 360 theta bins in each, it's incredibly slow (minutes).

I tried using `Wedge()` patches, but can't get them to render correctly in the polar projection. Here is sample code showing both approaches:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

# Theta coordinates in degrees

theta1=45
theta2=80

# Radius coordinates

r1 = 0.4
r2 = 0.5

# Plot using bar()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[6,6], subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
theta_mid = np.deg2rad((theta1 + theta2)/2)
theta_width = np.deg2rad(theta2 - theta1)
height = r2 - r1
ax.bar(x=theta_mid, height = height, width=theta_width, bottom=r1)
ax.set_rlim(0, 1)
plt.savefig('bar.png')

# Plot using Wedge()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[6,6], subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
patches = []
patches.append( Wedge(center=(0, 0), r = r1, theta1=theta1, theta2=theta2, width = r2-r1, color='blue'))
p = PatchCollection(patches)
ax.add_collection(p)
ax.set_rlim(0, 1)
plt.savefig('wedge.png')
```

The outputs of each are:

**Bar**

[image]

**Wedge**

[image]

I've tried using radians for the wedge (because polar plots usually want their angle values in radians). That didn't help.

Am I missing something in how I'm using the Wedge? If I add thousands of Wedges to my Patch collection should I have any expectation it will be faster than `bar()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking this was an actual bug, I opened this issue https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/22717 on matplotlib where one of the maintainers nicely pointed out that I should be using `Rectangle()` instead of `Wedge()`.

The solution they provided is

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[6,6], subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
p = PatchCollection([Rectangle((np.deg2rad(theta1), r1), theta_width, height, color='blue')])
ax.add_collection(p)
ax.set_rlim(0, 1)
plt.savefig('wedge.png')
```